# Function pointer points to nothing — how do I avoid this?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, function-pointers

I currently have a typedef pointer function that doesn't point to anything which result to a Segmentation fault (core dumped). I am trying to think of a solution to avoid it but can't think of any so far.

My code:

```
typedef void (*MenuFunction)(System*);

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    ...
    /* While loop for my menu */ 
    while(1)
    {
        printf("Main Menu\n");
        printf("%s\n", menu[0].text);
        printf("%s\n", menu[1].text);
        printf("%s\n", menu[2].text);
        printf("Select your option (1-3): ");
        (*getMenuChoice(menu))(&system);
    }
}

/* Function that points to the menu function */
MenuFunction getMenuChoice(MenuItem * menu)
{
    MenuFunction function = NULL;
    char select[50];
    fgets(select, 50, stdin);
    if(select[strlen(select)-1] == '\n')
    {      
        switch(select[0])
        {
            case '1':
                function = menu[0].function;
                break;
            case '2':
                function = menu[1].function;
                break;
            case '3':    
                function = menu[2].function;
                exit(0);
                break;
            default:
                printf("Invalid option\n");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        readRestOfLine();
        printf("Error: buffer overflow. Please try again, entering less data");
    }
    return function;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Right now, the solution I came up with was to create a function with nothing in it so I can have the function to point to something. I don't think this is ideal but it will do in the short run.

```
void skip()
{ }
```

Comment: Is it building?

Comment: Perhaps you should check what `getMenuChoice` returns before using it? Always a good thing to do when you have a function that can return a null pointer.

Comment: This needs a [mcve].

Comment: You should probably check what `fgets` return as well, or you many not always use a valid index when checking for the newline.

Comment: If it points to nothing, it is `NULL` (deducted from _your_ code). So you could just check if it's `NULL` and not call it in that case or take some other appropriate action.

Comment: You should be sure to initialize your `MenuItem`s when you create them, or at least before you use them.  If there are some of the function pointers that are *intended* to not point to any function, then be sure to set them to `NULL`.  The existence of even one such in the whole system then implies that you must perform a NULL check before attempting to use any of the function pointers.  If you do not exercise sufficient discipline to ensure that your function pointers are either valid or NULL, then there is no good way to check whether they are valid.

Comment: The posted code assumes (I.E. not part of the posted code fragment) there is a table (instances of a struct).  The normal logic is to 1) get a choice from the user 2) validate the choice 3) execute the function directly from the table rather than copying the function pointer from the table to another pointer

Comment: the posted code contains two variable names that will produce conflicts.  `select` is a well known library function, found in `sys/select.h` and `unistd.h`.   `system` is a well known library function found in `stdlib.h`.   Suggest using different names for those variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A great strategy for managing all pointers (data functions as well as function pointers) is: have them always point to something valid, or be null.  That is:

1. When you declare a pointer variable, always initialize it, either to point to something valid, or to NULL.
2. Before using a pointer, make sure it's not NULL.
3. When you do anything that would invalidate a pointer, set it back to NULL.

In your case, you're following rule 1 already, when you initialize

```
MenuFunction function = NULL;
```

So your `getMenuChoice()` function returns NULL if the choice was invalid.  Nothing wrong with that, it's a common pattern.

What you need to additionally do is comply with rule 2.  Right now you've got

```
(*getMenuChoice(menu))(&system);
```

which is kind of a mouthful: you call `getMenuChoice()`, then immediately call the function that it returned a pointer to.  Split this up into several lines:

```
MenuFunction fp;
fp = getMenuChoice(menu);
if(fp == NULL)
    fprintf(stderr, "invalid choice\n");
else
    (*fp)(&system);
```

Here, we capture `getMenuChoice`'s return value in a new variable `fp`, and we test to make sure it's not NULL before we call it.

[P.S. In your case, you don't need to worry about my rule 3.]

Answer (score 1):

To avoid 'this' seg fault event:

Check that the instance of the typedef contains other than NULL before calling the function via the instance of the typedef